# How to catch stock Android Clock application events?

Tags: android, events, timer, alarm

I am developing a small time-management application for Android. I use the stock Android Clock application. I am interested in the alarm clock and timer functions and i learned how to create them from my application. This is code that i use for it (alarm e.g.):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM){{
       putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, 5);
       putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, 0);
       putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_DAYS, alarmDays);
       putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true);
    }};

    startActivity(intent);
```

And now i want to catch some events when user interact with alarm and timer:

- When alarm is turned off
- When alarm is snoozed
- When timer is turned off

Then i want to perform some actions.
How is it possible to implement or what information i have to investigate for it?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I highly doubt it. Even the AOSP Clock app probably doesn't let you know this. And most Android phones don't actually have the AOSP app, but their own Clock apps. You'd be better off making your own Clock app.

Comment: @TheWanderer Thank you, I will listen to your advice.